# Thread Safe Accessing Enums in Java

Tags: java, enums, thread-safety

I want to know that the following code can be used in multi-threaded environment thread safely. I hope to use Task class as an accessing layer.

```
public class Task {
    public static enum TaskList {

        TASK_A {

            @Override
            void doProcess() {
                System.out.println("processing task A");

            }
        },
        TASK_B {
            @Override
            void doProcess() {
                System.out.println("processing task B");

            }
        },
        TASK_C {
            @Override
            void doProcess() {
                System.out.println("processing task C");
            }
        };

        abstract void doProcess();
    }
}
```

This is how it is going to be used.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //following code will be executed in multiple threads.

                Task.TaskList task = Task.TaskList.TASK_A;
                task.doProcess();

            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: I'd say you should not put logic into the enum. Instead give the enum to you task which may then use a switch or something like this to figure out what needs to be done. Whether the execution will be thread safe depends on what your doProcess method is actually doing. Please provide more information.

Comment: doProcess method calls some static methods in different classes.

Comment: Thread safety depends totally on what those methods do when you've written them.  We cannot tell if your code is thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Using enums has little to do with thread safety.

Your code (as presented here in the question) is thread-safe. But the following isn't:

```
public class Task {
    public static enum TaskList {

        TASK_A {
            int x = 0;

            @Override
            void doProcess() {
                x++;
                System.out.println("processing task A: " + x);

            }
        };

        abstract void doProcess();
    }
}
```

As you see, it being an enum has no bearing on thread safety. What matters is whether the object (enum value in this case) has any internal state that can change without being properly synchronized, and whether everything that the actual code calls is thread-safe as well.